# From Free-Form linguistic input to function expression to calculate spheroid surface

Tags: geometry, entity, free-form-input

I need to calculate the surface area of an oblate spheroid.  My first step is to get the surface equation from Free-Form input. But I have trouble converting to a WM function and replace the focus point and the major axis radius coefficients with my values.

```
SurfaceData[Entity["Surface", "Spheroid"], "Image"]
SurfaceData[Entity["Surface", "Spheroid"], "SurfaceArea"]
sphOblated = Simplify[% /. x_String :> ToExpression[a, c]]
{a -> Sqrt[2], c -> 1}/%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler method

```
SurfaceData[Entity["Surface", "Spheroid"], "SurfaceArea"][Sqrt[2],1]
```

which instantly returns

```
2*Pi*(2 + Sqrt[2]*ArcSinh[1])
```